# writing unit test case for a functiion in python where @retry is involved

Tags: python, python-unittest

i have a function in python in athena.py file

```
@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=10,
       wait_exponential_multiplier=300,
       wait_exponential_max=1 * 60 * 1000)
def poll_status(_id):
    result = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=_id)
    state = result['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
    if state == 'SUCCEEDED':
        return result
    elif state == 'FAILED':
        return result
    else:
        raise Exception
```

where client is reference of boto3.client like this:

```
client = boto3.client('athena', 'us-west-2')
```

i have written the unit test for this function using unittest in test_athena.py

```
@mock.patch('boto3.client')
def test_poll_status(self, mock_client):
    event1 = {'QueryExecution': {'Status': {'State': 'SUCCEEDED'}}}
    instance = mock_client.return_value()
    instance.get_query_execution.return_value = event1
    result = athena.poll_status('id')
    expected_result = event1
    self.assertEqual(expected_result, result)
```

But this fails. I don't know the reason as i wrote test cases for other functions in similar fashion but this one does not work.

```
"botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"
```

This error is thrown

imports in athena.py

```
import boto3
from retrying import retry
```

imports in test_athena.py

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
```

Comment: "This fails" is not a useful error message. Explain how it fails.

Comment: "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials"  This error is thrown

Comment: could you also list your imports?

Comment: done..have a look

Comment: Is the question about this specific failure? Or about why the test is taking a long time? Or about why the patch doesn't work?

Comment: test takes a lot of time then fails. i want to know the reason and solution to this

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to make your test pass - or fail fast.

The fail-fast part is because I'm mocking the retry piece.
Then, I'm mocking a specific function of the client object.

I'm attaching a complete file - including the original code, the test, and a 'main'. It passes on my machine.

```
import boto3
from retrying import retry
import retrying
import unittest
from unittest import mock

client = boto3.client('athena', 'us-west-2')

@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=10,
       wait_exponential_multiplier=300,
       wait_exponential_max=1 * 60 * 1000)
def poll_status(_id):
    result = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=_id)
    state = result['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
    if state == 'SUCCEEDED':
        return result
    elif state == 'FAILED':
        return result
    else:
        raise Exception        

dummy_retry = retrying.Retrying(stop_max_attempt_number = 10, wait_fixed=1)

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('retrying.Retrying', new = lambda **kwargs: dummy_retry)
    @mock.patch.object(client, 'get_query_execution')
    def test_poll_status(self, mock_client):
        event1 = {'QueryExecution': {'Status': {'State': 'SUCCEEDED'}}}
        mock_client.return_value = event1
        result = poll_status('id')
        expected_result = event1
        self.assertEqual(expected_result, result)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: client instance is also used in other functions and so i can not move its definition inside the poll_status method

Comment: What's the failure you're seeing?

Comment: same..botocore one

Comment: I've added the entire code. Could you please give it a try (as a file on its own)? If this passes, then the cause of the failure on your side is probably something else.

Answer (score 0):

Is you system configured with the aws cli. It seems like you might not have configured aws cli with appropriate access key id and secret key.

Comment: it is configured.

Comment: are you able to locate the .aws/ directory at /~ with 2 files namely credentials and config ?

Comment: where do they files get created.... i remember running aws configure command and providing account id and sercet access key... then it must be configured right?

Comment: In the home directory. Try "cd .aws". These are hidden directories that are not listed openly.